# After migration to SharePoint Online some documents that did not move over are saying they are checked out to a user when they are not

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

We migrated from SP 2013 to SharePoint Online (SPO).  However, after migrating, some of the documents did not copy.  They won't copy because they are saying they are checked out to a user but they aren't.  I have checked the Office Upload center and Manage files which have no checked in version in Library settings but they are not there.  We have to move these off of the old servers ASAP.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During document this kind of issue we might see. There we need to check couple of things.

**First, ensure documents are not in checked out report**

Go to the library settings page, then click on managed checkout document links, there SharePoint site collection administrator can all checked out documents, and then can check those documents in.

As you said, there is version of those documents, then you might turn of the versioning settings both in source and target library.

And also, from the library **versioning** settings page, In the Require Check Out section, under the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" question, select **No**.

Note :

- If you are using the shareGate migration tool, you can generate the checked out inventory using the tool, then find those documents whether it's available in the report.

**Make sure those failed documents are not corrupt**

Many times, it happens if the documents are corrupted, we cannot migrate those documents, so we need to verify this.

Download any of those files from source, and open it and manually upload it to the target library.. if you are able to upload, then the document is fine.

And also verify the target document URL length, try to migrate in relatively shorter URL location.

Finally, if nothing works, and if you relatively few documents, try to migrate those using PowerShell script or if you have larger amounts of such files, you may approach to migration tool vendor for their help.